# Content Security Policy preventing images from loading

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, content-security-policy

I have an express app which is loading some external assets, but they're getting blocked by CSP. I've never had this issue before, but this is the first time im using passport.js and helmet.js within an app so maybe this has something to do with their configuration?

```
Refused to load the image 'https://fake-url.com' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".
```

I've tried adding a meta tag to allow images from external sources but this seems to have no effect. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: List your meta tag.

Comment: sorry, this is the one i'm using:  `meta(http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; connect-src 'self' *;font-src 'self' *; img-src 'self' *; style-src 'self' *; script-src 'self' *")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
content="default-src 'none'
```

This prevents loading resources from any source. Remove it.

Then change it to:

```
default-src 'self' fake-url.com';
```

More info bout the HTTP **Content-Security-Policy** response header below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy

https://content-security-policy.com/